# A Cell in Table Color Change C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, background, cell

ASP.NET Microsoft Visual Studio 10 -  I Created a table in Design View 25 x 25. Now at the Page Load I want to change the colour of the Row 1 2nd Cell BackColour to Orange.

My ID of table is "tab". My Background of the whole table doesn't change upon page load. I get this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

There is no error if I take out `"tab1.Rows[1].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Orange;"` but still table background colour not purple.

```
   Table tab1 = new Table();
   tab1.ID = "tab";

   tab1.BackColor = Color.Purple;
   tab1.Rows[1].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating new table

```
Table tab1 = new Table();
```

this is not the one you added in designer.

you need to find the id of table you added by the designer and change that one. go to designer view and check the ID of the table. for example if it is `table1`

```
table1.BgColor = "Purple";
table1.Rows[1].Cells[2].BgColor = "Orange";
```

if this is asp.net aplication make sure you have set `runat ="server"` in your table

Comment: The name 'table1' does not exist in the current context. just table1.BackColor = Color.Purple; got error underlining table1, thanks

Comment: table1.BgColor = Color.Orange;    , I placed runat = "server" then the error underlined was BackColor I changed it to bgcolor then Color.Purple; error underlined.

Comment: @user2357207 you need to give string value for BgColor

Comment: Already figured out the string color, but thanks btw, wouldnt have got it if not for runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

error is coming because right now your table is not having any `cell/ data`.

To assign color of `Row[1]cell[2]` your table need to have `Row[1]cell[2].`

So before assigning color to cell give your table the `datasource` and then try changing background color of cells.

Suppose `ds` is your `datasource`
then,

```
Table tab1 = new Table();
tab1.ID = "tab";
tab1.runat = "server";
tab1.DataSource = ds;
tab1.BackColor = Color.Purple;
tab1.Rows[1].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

Now if your datasource is having the expected no of data then you will see the positive results,

Answer (score 0):

Rows and Cells only exist after you have set the tables DataSource. If you check Rows.Count you will see that it is 0.
So set the DataSource and then change the backcolor of your cell.

Comment: hey I am talking about just the normal Table, not any grid view. If you still mean the normal table whatchu mean? thanks

Comment: Just as veer b singh answered. There are no cells without data. At least not the way you showed in your code.